# GA's user flow doesn't work with "/?page=home" type of queries?

Tags: google-analytics

[image]

My whole website uses only the first '/' path, with PHP's GET queries to navigate. Example:

```
/?page=home
/?page=login
/?page=join&type=1
/?page=download&version=123
...
```

For some reason, google's user-flow chart doesn't like that and groups everything into a node called '/'.
I tried using `.htaccess` in my website to convert queries to paths. But it was too much for what it's worth, I ended up giving up.. Is there any way I can solve this from Google Analytics' side?

Comment: You might use a search and replace filter in the view settings that replaces "/?page=" with a slash (so you'd get just e.g. "/home"). Two caveats, it does not help with data already collected and it breaks inpage analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it via Navigation reports feature. but ui is a bit clanky so it's difficult to see a little gear icon. But you have to define all of your pages that you want to include in Flow as a navigation type. here is a useful example.

http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/10/19/path-analysis-in-google-analytics-with-flow-visualization/

Comment: Thank you. I just read that same article minutes before posting. I'm not sure if it solves the main problem, because having to manually input all the pages one by one would be a real pain. There must be a way to group URLs by queries instead of paths ?

Comment: I had a similar php website. here is a sample flow configuration that i applied. ss: https://yardimcikitap.com/yas/ga-nav-flow.jpg  i hope it helps.